# Using Case statement in Where clause in Oracle SQL

Tags: select, conditional-statements, case, where-clause, oracle12c

I have a select statement like below

```
select * 
from employees 
where emp_id <= v_emp_id;
```

I want this `emp_id` to be `<= v_emp_id` if country is not USA.

If country is USA, then I want `emp_id` to be `= v_usa_emp_id`.

Comment: 'where (country_code <> 'US' and emp_id <= v_emp_id) or (country_code = 'US' and emp_id = v_usa_emp_id)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. I have assumed that `country` is an attribute in the table `employees` of data type `VARCHAR`.

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE 
    (emp_id = v_emp_id AND country = 'USA') 
    OR (emp_id <= v_emp_id AND country != 'USA')
```

You might want to take a look at [WHERE](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-where/), [OR](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-or/) and [AND](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-and/).

Quoting the `OR` page linked above:

> If you use multiple logical operators in a statement, Oracle evaluates the OR operators after the NOT and AND operators. However, you can change the order of evaluation by using parentheses.